# EC2 free tier 85% usage reached afer 7 days

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've setup one EC2 instance on aws.
And after 7 days, I've got already this message:
has exceeded 85% of the usage limit for one or more AWS Free Tier-eligible services for the month of April.

How could it be, that in 7 days, which have 168 hours, that aws comes up and says:

644.559167 Hrs  from 750 hours used?

do I understand this wrong, how they calculate the hours?

Comment: If you run multiple instances, they will add up. So in 7 days you could run  4 instances concurrently, which in total will give you about 641 hours.

Comment: thx, this was the problem

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind I will make an answer with some extra details and links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The importing thing about EC2 Free tier limit of 750 hours is that it is **cumulative**. So it does not apply per `t2.micro` instance, but it applies to all `t2.micro` instances in total.

This means that you can run within the free tier usage, e.g.:

- 1 x `t2.micro` instance for 750 hours per month, or
- 2 x `t2.micro` instances concurrently for 375 hours per month, or
- 4 x `t2.micro` instances for 187.5 hours per month.

In all the above cases, the **total usage** of `t2.micro` adds up to 750 hours per month. If you exceed it, you pay normal rate for the excess time.